# Publish a Locator Service with a place-name alias table

Tags: arcgis-server, geolocation, alias

I am trying to publish a locator service with support for a place-name alias table, in ArcGIS for Server 10.3.

It should function similar to the [Esri World Geocode Server](http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/) which allows users to search for place names such as "Starbucks" over an extent.

So far I have not been able to publish the locator when the alias table is attached.  I found [this article](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/00156-locator-with-place-name-alias-table-is-not-supported.htm) which describes how the place-name tables are not supported with published services.

Does anyone know how Esri was able to accomplish this with the World Geocode Server?

Answer (score 1):

We tried to solve this problem directly inside the locator:

```
<alias_list name="CityAliases">
      <alias_def>
        <alt>New York</alt>
        <alt>NY</alt>
        <alt>etc</alt>
      </alias_def>
      <alias_def>
        <alt>Portland</alt>
        <altPT</alt>
        <alt>ARE</alt>
        <alt>UAE</alt>
        <alt>blbalbla</alt>
      </alias_def>
      <alias_def>
```

The first (alt)
New York
describes the original name from the attribute table, 
the following  (alt)
are the alternative names
            NY
            etc

This worked for the Locator in 10.2.2. I did not try that with the new locator, But right now I am on in, because we upgraded our Server to 10.3 :-)